# TeamCity - Checkout rule

Tags: tfs, msbuild, teamcity

I am using TeamCity for CI. 
And I have a requirement to read teamcity checkout rule using MSBuild.
I tried using `%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%` .But it is giving the directory to which the checkout happens. Is it possible to get the TFS source path of this checkout rule.

For eg: my checkout rule is as below

```
+:./project1 => source/MyProj1
+:./project2 => source/MyProj2.
```

Can I read the paths `$/MyTFSRoot/Dev/Project1` and `$/MyTFSRoot/Dev/Project2`

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity does not expose checkout rules directly, however, you can put the tfs part of your checkout rule into a parameter.
Replace `./project1` as, for example, `%rule.project1%` and `./project2` as `%rule.project2%` in your checkout rules. Then go to parameters section of your build configuration. You will see 2 undefined parameters `rule.project1` and `rule.project2`. Assign the values to them (`./project1` and `./project2` correspondingly).

After this is done, you can reference `%rule.project1%` and `%rule.project2%` in your scripts, if you are using, for example, command line build step with the script in it

For the parameters to be seen outside of TeamCity managed scripts, name them `env.rule.project1` and `env.rule.project2`. This way the parameters will be passed to the build as environmental variables that can be easily obtained in most cases